# LOG Space Issues -- Figuring Out the Disk Space needed for DAG CopyQueueLength

Tags: exchange-2016, dag

I have a DAG Database, DAG1, with 300000 CopyQueueLength. The Status for the copy is Failed and Suspended. In researching the problem I found that a reseed is needed for the database to get exchange copy up and running-- However I'm concerned about the space on that DAG database needs to copy over to the EXCH2 server.

Does CopyQueueLength denote the items to be copied or the size in kb?

What should I take into account for the space required before running a reseed?

### background

- EXCH1, and EXCH2 are in a DAG
- EXCH1, and EXCH2 are VMware Servers

Comment: Remove the failing copy and reseed once again. In general, if the circular logging set to disabled, you'll get the entire size of the database size through the logs.

Comment: Agree with Vick Vega. Reseed again to get exchange copy up and running. Copy queue length indicates the number of log files waiting to be copied and inspected. So this value doesn't identify how many log files have yet to be copied to the destination mailbox server. Or you can refer to this.https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/56369741-3cbc-4b77-b1a5-c7fa77133b88/copyqueuelength?forum=exchange2010

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have a 700GB Database on EXCH1 that needs to reseed to EXCH2. It sounds like I need to take into account the log files(150GB). Therefor make sure that EXCH2 has at least total disk size of 850GB, and add some wiggle room. Are my assumptions correct? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, I set the corresponding disk from EXCH1 to EXCH2 to the same size. When running the reseed process the logs were consolidated between the servers. I ran the copy via the https://localhost/ecp

1. Selected Servers> Databases> Database
2. Selected Update in the right hand side
3. Selected EXCH1 as the server to reseed from
4. let the reseed run

At the start of the copy, I saw the Used Disk space reduce within a couple minutes-- I assume this was do to whatever consolidation process that the reseed process runs.